# go unit test runs from %APPDATA%

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am trying to run some of my Go unit tests using "go test" but the test executable is built and run from my machine's %APPDATA%/local/temp directory. My PC has IT enforcement which blocks any unrecognized executable from being run other than from a pre-sanctioned directory (i.e C:/dev/projects"). All my Go source code are in that directory, including my *_test.go files. Is there a way to tell the Go test module to build and run from the current directory?

Comment: Does `TMPDIR=c:/dev/projects/tmp go test` not work for you (or whatever the Windows equivalent is)?

Answer (score 3):

> Yes you can.

Setting temp directory before executing the `go test`. By default temp directory environment variable gets evaluated in the order of `TMP`, `TEMP`, `USERPROFILE`, Windows directory; refer to [msdn doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992(v=vs.85).aspx).

Basically it complies the go test under given temp directory and execute it.

```
C:\> cd dev\projects\src\mygotest
C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest>echo %CD%
C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest

C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest>set TMP=%CD%

C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest>go test -x
WORK=C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest\go-build306298926
mkdir -p $WORK\mygotest\_test\
mkdir -p $WORK\mygotest\_test\_obj_test\
cd C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest
"C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\compile.exe" -o "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926\\mygotest\\_test\\mygotest.a" -trimpath "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926" -p main -complete -buildid 86cb7a423d355c7468ad98c4f8bffe77b68d2265 -D _/C_/dev/projects/src/mygotest -I "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926" -pack "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\sample.go" "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\sample_test.go"
cd $WORK\mygotest\_test
"C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\compile.exe" -o "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926\\mygotest\\_test\\main.a" -trimpath "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926" -p main -complete -D "" -I "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926\\mygotest\\_test" -I "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926" -pack "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926\\mygotest\\_test\\_testmain.go"
cd .
"C:\\Go\\pkg\\tool\\windows_amd64\\link.exe" -o "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926\\mygotest\\_test\\mygotest.test.exe" -L "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926\\mygotest\\_test" -L "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926" -w -extld=gcc -buildmode=exe "C:\\dev\\projects\\src\\mygotest\\go-build306298926\\mygotest\\_test\\main.a"
$WORK\mygotest\_test\mygotest.test.exe
Hello, playground
PASS
ok      mygotest        0.526s

C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest>
```

***Note:*** `TMP` set to current terminal session only, it doesn't affect system environment variable.

Important thing to note from above test output is `WORK=C:\dev\projects\src\mygotest\go-build306298926`.

Happy testing!